Save Data to GoogleBigQuery with Scrapy Spider run on AWS Lambda
I have a Scrapy spider that runs perfectly on my local machine. It scrapes data and saves the results to Google BigQuery (GBQ) using a custom pipeline. However, when I deploy the same spider to AWS Lambda, it fails to save the data to GBQ.
The weird part is that:
I can see the scraped data in the Lambda logs.
No errors are thrown during the Lambda execution.
It seems like the pipeline isn't being imported or used, but I can't figure out why.
Code
Commented lines are used to run code locally
def real_estate_scraper(event, contxt):
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['ITEM_PIPELINES'] =  {
    "real_estate_prices.pipelines.SaveToGBQPipeline": 300,
    }

    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)

    process.crawl(KolejNa19Spider)
    process.crawl(ModernMokotowSpider)
    process.crawl(StacjaWolaSpider)
    process.crawl(Zelazna54Spider)

    process.start()

#event = 1
#contxt = 1

#real_estate_scraper(event,contxt)

Pipeline
class SaveToGBQPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):        
        load_dotenv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', '.env'))
        json_key_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'real-estate-tracker-437718-4857741a8e36.json')
        
        self.credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            json_key_path,
            scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"],
        )
        
        self.client = bigquery.Client(
            credentials=self.credentials,
            project=self.credentials.project_id,
        )
        
        self.items = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.items.append(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):      
        for item in self.items:
            print(item)

        df = pd.DataFrame(self.items)
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])  

        pandas_gbq.to_gbq(
            df,
            "real-estate-tracker-437718.real_estate_dataset.prices",
            project_id="real-estate-tracker-437718",
            if_exists="append",
            location="US",
            credentials=self.credentials,  # Use the same credentials
        )

Project structure 
\---image
    |   Dockerfile
    |   image_update.sh
    |   requirements.txt
    |   
    \---source
        |   main.py
        |   real-estate-tracker-437718-4857741a8e36.json
        |   scrapy.cfg
        |   __init__.py
        |   
        \---real_estate_prices
            |   items.py
            |   middlewares.py
            |   pipelines.py
            |   settings.py
            |   __init__.py
            |   
            +---spiders
            |   |   kolej_na_19.py
            |   |   modern_mokotow.py
            |   |   oval_sky.py
            |   |   stacja_wola.py
            |   |   zelazna_54.py
            |   |   __init__.py


Is the pipeline present in the list of activated pipelines?

No, enabled pipelines is empty
